# Open parent dropdown if child contains active class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple dropdown with checkboxes inside. I have an active class on the child LI elements which simulates a checked box. I want to check if the dropdown has a child li element with an active class. If it does i want the dropdown active class to be added automatically on page load.

#### Here is my JS Fiddle


https://jsfiddle.net/p5jzgdqn/3/

### Here is my jQuery

```
//make list a dropdown
$(".category-filters-section-title").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul.category-filters-area-list").toggleClass("filter-dropdown-active");
});

//open dropdown if any of the li children contains the class "active-filter"
$( document ).ready(function() {


$(".category-filters-area-section").each(function() {
  if ($(this).has(".active-filter").length) {
    // find the parent and add class ONLY if the "IF" is true
    $(this)
      .closest("ul.category-filters-area-list")
      .addClass("filter-dropdown-active");
  }
});

});
```

I need to target (this) element starting at the parent `<ul>` element because there is going to be multiple dropdowns. But one should be okay for this example.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things stopping your code from working

```
$(".category-filters-area-section").each(function() {
  if ($(this).has(".active-filter").length) {
```

needs to be

```
$(".category-filters-area-section").each(function() {
  if ($(this).has(".active-filter")) {
```

without .length as `.has` returns a boolean.  You could have used

```
$(".category-filters-area-section").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find(".active-filter").length) {
```

Next:

```
    // find the parent and add class ONLY if the "IF" is true
    $(this)
      .closest("ul.category-filters-area-list")
      .addClass("filter-dropdown-active");
```

here, `this` refers to each of the `.category-filters-area-section` but in your HTML (in the fiddle), the `-section` is the parent of the `-list`, so `.closest()` won't find it, so this could be:

```
    // find the parent and add class ONLY if the "IF" is true
    $(this)
      .find("ul.category-filters-area-list")
      .addClass("filter-dropdown-active");
```

to get the .list that is a child of the .section.  However, this will cause problems if you have multiple .list entries in each .section (hard to tell as your fiddle only had 1).

---

Alternatively, you can find the `li.active` and work back from there:

```
  $(".category-filters-area-list li.active-filter")
    .parent()
    .addClass("filter-dropdown-active");
```

Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/2Lx8op6f/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".advanced-filter").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).hasClass('active-filter'))
  $(this).parent('ul').addClass('filter-dropdown-active');
});
```

Oh i should look up instead of look down.

Cheers.

Comment: Nice to know you got it working, anyway don't you think using  $(this).parent('ul').addClass('filter-dropdown-active'); in the click of a child element instead of looping is more performance-wise than looping over elements?

Comment: @AwSnap *I want the dropdown active class to be added automatically on page load* - child element *loads* with active class, so set parent active class: on load

Comment: You don't need the .each, just put the `if` inside the selector:  `$(".advanced-filter.active-filter").parent("ul").addClass(...`